Julia MLJ Forest Load:Error: MethodError: no method matching BetaML.Bmlj.RandomForestRegressor()
Helllo,
I have trouble using any kind of decision tree model from MLJ. I have tried 3 packages from MLJ, DecisionTree, Scikit, and now this BetaML. This only happens when I'm trying to train some kind of decision tree. I works fine with other MLJLinearModels and with XGBoost. I always get the same error. The error is coming from the following function:
 function machine_train_predict(df::DataFrame, df_train::DataFrame, model_name::String; args...)
        models = Dict(
        "xgb_reg"=> ["XGBoost" => "XGBoostRegressor"],
        "ridge_reg"=> ["MLJLinearModels" => "RidgeRegressor"],
        "lasso_reg"=> ["MLJLinearModels" => "LassoRegressor"],
        "rf_reg" => ["BetaML" => "RandomForestRegressor"],
        "lin_reg" => ["MLJLinearModels" => "LinearRegressor"],
        "log_class" => ["MLJLinearModels" => "LogisticClassifier"],
        "rf_class" => ["DecisionTree" => "RandomForestClassifier"],
        "xgb_class" => ["XGBoost" => "XGBoostClassifier"]
        )

        y, X =  machine_input(df_train; rng=123)
        y = coerce(y, Continuous)

        mod = models[model_name][1]
        p = mod[1]
        m = mod[2]
        mname = model_name
        Model = @eval @load $(m) pkg=$(p) verbosity=0
        model = Model()

        # train machine and get parameters

        m1 = machine(model, X, y) |> fit!

    #     prepare test set for machine predictions
        y, X =  machine_input(df)
        y = coerce(y, Continuous)
    #     predict
        yhat = MLJ.predict_mode(m1, X)
        return yhat
    end

And the error:
Training. Dataset: global. Iteration N: 1ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching BetaML.Bmlj.RandomForestRegressor()
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 33750, while current world is 33793.

Closest candidates are:
  BetaML.Bmlj.RandomForestRegressor(; n_trees, max_depth, min_gain, min_records, max_features, splitting_criterion, β, rng) (method too new to be called from this world context.)
   @ BetaML ~/.julia/packages/BetaML/8WVUG/src/Bmlj/Trees_mlj.jl:219
  BetaML.Bmlj.RandomForestRegressor(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Function, ::Float64, ::Random.AbstractRNG) (method too new to be called from this world context.)
   @ BetaML ~/.julia/packages/BetaML/8WVUG/src/Bmlj/Trees_mlj.jl:193
  BetaML.Bmlj.RandomForestRegressor(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) (method too new to be called from this world context.)
   @ BetaML ~/.julia/packages/BetaML/8WVUG/src/Bmlj/Trees_mlj.jl:193

Stacktrace:
  [1] (::var"#machine_train_predict#38"{var"#machine_train_predict#11#39"})(df::DataFrame, df_train::DataFrame, model_name::String; args::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:250
  [2] (::var"#machine_train_predict#38"{var"#machine_train_predict#11#39"})(df::DataFrame, df_train::DataFrame, model_name::String)
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:230
  [3] (::var"#train_rescore#36"{var"#train_rescore#10#37"})(df::DataFrame, df_train::DataFrame, model_name::String; args::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:223
  [4] (::var"#train_rescore#36"{var"#train_rescore#10#37"})(df::DataFrame, df_train::DataFrame, model_name::String)
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:219
  [5] (::var"#proto_train#32"{var"#proto_train#7#33"})(df::DataFrame, df_t::DataFrame, model_name::String; nflds::Int64, args::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:nfolds,), Tuple{Int64}}})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:211
  [6] (::var"#evaluate_model#42"{var"#evaluate_model#13#43"})(paths::String, output::String, dss::String, niter::Int64, model_name::String; nfolds::Int64, args::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:284
  [7] (::var"#global_evaluate#40"{var"#global_evaluate#12#41"})(paths::String, output::String, ds::Vector{String}, itern::Int64, model_name::String; nfolds::Int64, args::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:270
  [8] global_evaluate
    @ ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:267 [inlined]
  [9] main(args::Vector{String})
    @ Main ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:475
 [10] top-level scope
    @ ~/exports/10fold_ml_model-nocache-by-iter.jl:479 

The error is always related to world age and the corresponding MLJInterface of the model in use.
Please help. I have been trying to find a solution for days.
I'm trying to make predictions. The function in question corresponds to the training and prediction step of my script. I wasn't expecting to error because previous regressor models (linear, lasso, ridge, xgboost) under the MLJ framework worked fine.

Hi, BetaML maintener here. Can you try updating your packages? The release with the package reorganized with that function is from January, so you should just be fine with the updated packages. A suggestion: don't work in the global environment, rather create an environment specific for each of your yor ML task/project Environments in Julia are cheap and contribute to reduce package dependency problems.

I have tried just now and with a recent version of MLJ (v0.20.5) it works with the trick below:
Type this on a script Foo.jl in an empty directory:
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(@__DIR__) # Activate the environment on the directory of this script. The first time the environment is "created" by making in this directory 2 files, Project.toml and Manifest.toml
Pkg.add("MLJ")
Pkg.add("BetaML")

using MLJ
import BetaML  # <--- trick here
X = rand(100,5)
y = [r[2]+r[3]^2-r[5] for r in eachrow(X)]
model_name = "rf_reg"
function predict_y(model_name,X,y)
    models = Dict(
        "xgb_reg"=> ["XGBoost" => "XGBoostRegressor"],
        "ridge_reg"=> ["MLJLinearModels" => "RidgeRegressor"],
        "lasso_reg"=> ["MLJLinearModels" => "LassoRegressor"],
        "rf_reg" => ["BetaML" => "RandomForestRegressor"],
        "lin_reg" => ["MLJLinearModels" => "LinearRegressor"],
        "log_class" => ["MLJLinearModels" => "LogisticClassifier"],
        "rf_class" => ["DecisionTree" => "RandomForestClassifier"],
        "xgb_class" => ["XGBoost" => "XGBoostClassifier"]
    )
    mod = models[model_name][1]
    p = mod[1]
    m = mod[2]
    Model = @eval @load $(m) pkg=$(p) verbosity=0
    model = Model()

    # train machine and get parameters
    m1 = machine(model, X, y) |> fit!
    ŷ  = predict_mode(m1, X)
    return ŷ
end
ŷ = predict_y(model_name,X,y)
hcat(y,ŷ)

As I wrote in the comment, it is always best to start a project on a dedicated environment.
Also BetaML works on standard arrays, not dataframes.
[EDIT]
Indeed, if @evel @load is done within a function, you end up with the issue you discovered.
I don't know exactly what MLJ.@load does and the reason behind it, but the trick is just to import the package providing the model, here BetaML, before calling that function.

Thanks so much for your help! you´re right it must be something related to env and packets management.
I need to use some of the packages for calculating performance and other stuff though.
Would you suggest that I isolate this part of the pipeline in its own directory environment? Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Also have you tried this when the code is inside a function?

@fnmelo: indeed, in a function you have that error, but it is enough to load (import) the package before calling the function. I have updated the answer. There could be other workarounds, but this works.

This works! Not just for BetaML but also for models from other packages. Thank you so much!
